# Adding the results of a function to an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have numerous input boxes that I'm trying to store the names of into an array. I'm  using this currently to get the names:

```
var getImplementedNames = function (selector){
    $(selector).each(function() {
        console.log($( this ).attr('name').replace('imp-', ''));
    });
}   

console.log(getImplementedNames('[id^=imp]'));
```

This works, but now I'd like to add all the reslts to an array. I've tried;

```
var array = [getImplementedNames('[id^=imp]')];

console.log(array);
```

Which returns an undefined array.

I'm not sure of how this is supposed to be properly handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

```
var getImplementedNames = function (selector) {
    return  $(selector).map(function () {
        return $(this).attr('name').replace('imp-', '');
    }).get();
}
```

usage

```
console.log(getImplementedNames('[id^=imp]'));
```

Read  [Return Value from function in JavaScript](http://hscripts.com/tutorials/javascript/return-value.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your function isn't currently returning anything. Try:

```
var getImplementedNames = function (selector){
    return $(selector).map(function() {
        return $( this ).attr('name').replace('imp-', '');
    });
}   

console.log(getImplementedNames('[id^=imp]'));
```